# Use @Media Width in CSS Width Calculation

Tags: css

I would like to dynamically calculate the width of an image based on the width of the window.

Current CSS which isn't working:

```
    .banner-image-side {
      width: calc((@media(width) - 1527px) / 2); 
    }
```

Comment: if it's based on the window width, you could use `100vw`

Answer (score 0):

Try to using `vw` unit for get with of window.

example:

```css
    .banner-image-side {
      width: calc((100vw - 1527px) / 2); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use vw

> vw ==> 1% of the viewport's width.

Documentation: [CSS values and units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)

```
.banner-image-side {
    width: calc((@media(vw) - 1527px) / 2); 
}
```

P.S: I think -1527px is too great a value to reduce with